# parse selective table rows in python with lxml and xpath

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml

below is the structure of the html file that i wish to parse

```
<tr data-mod-primary="true">
    <td>'some text'
<tr>
    <td>'some text'
<tr>
    <td>'some text'
<tr data-mod-primary="true">
    <td>'some text'
```

I am interested in parsing only the text under `<tr data-mod-primary="true">` and ignore other `<tr>`'s

I get all `<tr>` text through `.xpath('//tr/td/text()')` but this is not what I want. I have tried the below code after researching for solution for sometime:

```
.xpath('//tr[contains(@data-mod-primary="true",None)]/td/text()')
```

but this too gets me the text under all `<tr>` basically same result as `.xpath('//tr/td/text()')`

Any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@attr=value` to extract specific tr tags:

```
//tr[@data-mod-primary='true']/td/text()
```

Or if you use `contains`, it would be something like:

```
//tr[contains(@data-mod-primary, 'true')]/td/text()
```